# input type range fixed between min and max value

Tags: jquery, html, input, types, range

I want to fix drag input type range in between a max and a min value. My input type range has its min value 0 and max value 100. I want to control this drag between 20 to 80.

How to do it??

P.S. I am using normal jQuery.

I have done this much, now I want to control its dragging between a range, but I want to show the 100% range, user can only drag between 20 to 80

```
[code Fiddle][1]
```

I have found this link in stackover. I was trying to edit it but I couldn't find the solution.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EL4tf/)

Comment: please share some relevant code so that we can help you better

Comment: Please share some code so i can help you.

Comment: Do you not simply need to change the 'min' and 'max' values to 20 and 80, respectively?

Comment: Do you want drag only from 20 to 80 in 0 to 100 range of input.

Comment: Yes Ezhil. I want to drag between 20 to 80 in 0 to 100 range of input

Answer (score 1):

Demo: http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/demo_advanced.html
Check the Set "maximum interval size:" demo

```
<script>
$("#range_120").ionRangeSlider({
type: "double",
min: 0,
max: 100,
from: 30,
to: 70,
max_interval: 50   
});
 <script>
```

Comment: Set max_interval: 60 for choose between  20 to 80.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using HTML5 Range sliders:

```
<input id="slider1" type="range" min="20" max="80" step="10" />
```

Source: http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-range.php